# #1054 - Unknown column in field list

Tags: mysql, sql, join

it's my first time to use INNER JOIN

```
SELECT `xxx_storage.*`, `xxx_foods.*` FROM xxx_storage INNER JOIN xxx_foods ON `xxx_storage.food_id` = `xxx_foods.food_id`
```

The error I am getting is this:

```
#1054 - Unknown column 'xxx_storage.*' in 'field list'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the back ticks  :

```
SELECT xxx_storage.*,
       xxx_foods.*
FROM xxx_storage
INNER JOIN xxx_foods
 ON xxx_storage.food_id = xxx_foods.food_id
```

Back ticks are used for [MySQL Reserved words](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html) , they are used on single columns, not a list of them (*) , so when you are using them to wrap `Table.*` , MySQL automatically looks at it as a single column .

Comment: Or do `tablename`.`columnname`